# Which kind of grid format is this?

Tags: raster, gdal, ascii, format

in a project I got some raster files with the following content (header and data are in one txt file):

```
HOUR 17
MINUTES 30
YEAR 2012
MONTH 5
DAY 4
CITY Emilia;Bologna
NROWS 99
NCOLS 156
ULXMAP 11.2087224106
ULYMAP 44.5539582648
XDIM 0.0016666668
YDIM 0.0012500001
CELLE_TRUE 2999
CELLE_FALSE 1
0.15478748  0.15478748  0.15478748  0.15478748  0.15478748  
0.15478748  0.15478748  0.15478748  0.15478748  0.15478748  
0.15478748  0.15478748  0.077375025 0.018038042 0.01576243
[...]
```

I tried to identify the format but did not get far. It seems to be a "kind of" ESRI ASCII grid, but it features non-square pixels (as you can see), which is not supported by ESRI ASCII grid (AFAIK). It might be an Arc Grid format (I found this link: http://landcover.usgs.gov/faq_importing_arc.php) but then I am lost. GDAL does not recognize the format, QGIS and ArcGIS 10 don't like the format either. Does anybody know this particular format (coming from an Italian source)? Or give me a hint how to process it to an more "readable" format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only references to that exact grid format that I've found came from the book Urbanism on Tract: Application of Tracking Technologies in Urbansim, and specifically the chapter by Andres Sevtsuk and Carlo Ratti called Mobile Surveys. Here's the link:

http://books.google.ca/books?id=Uf9-YwlMaocC&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=HOUR+MINUTES+YEAR+MONTH+DAY+CITY+NROWS+NCOLS+ULXMAP+ULYMAP&source=bl&ots=kWZWvu7Qyr&sig=3orX823tzwGwqEt1Fx3jgkVCEd0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e-Y6UpntOejyyAGJ2oDgBg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=HOUR%20MINUTES%20YEAR%20MONTH%20DAY%20CITY%20NROWS%20NCOLS%20ULXMAP%20ULYMAP&f=false

There is also an Erlang parser for the format by the looks of it:

http://code.google.com/p/mrtyp/source/browse/trunk/ErlangMap/src/parser/ErlangParser.java?r=287

Comment: Thanks, John, I will have a look into it. That was already very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help.